# Using Ajax with Variable Amount of Form Data

Tags: php, ajax

I've gotten Ajax to work on simple forms, but when I try to generate multiple form elements in a loop I have trouble unpacking all that data and using it to update my database. Anyone have any input on how I could achieve this based on my code below? Basically, each line item has the potential to have its price updated. When the user clicks the submit button, it calls a function to Ajax, which should pass all the form data to price-update.php. There, it unpacks every $_POST and update the database accordingly.

Note: This code is reduced for visual ease. Some variables are used, but methods for initialization are not given.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/price-update.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
                alert('Data was submitted');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

//Multiple form elements generated depending on how many prices exist in database
<form>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Changes" />
    <table>
        <tbody> 
        <?php 
        $n = 0;
        for ($z = 0; $z < count($names); $z++) { ?>
            <tr id = "row-<?php echo $z; ?>">
                <td><input type="number" name ="price[]; ?>" class="price-update" value="" min="1" max="999999999" /></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" class="price-id" value="<?php echo $id_array[$n]; ?>" /></td>
                <?php $n++;?>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>

//price-update.php

<?php

    if($_POST) {

        //Uses SSL connection with mysqli
        require_once('connection.php');

        $IDs = array();
        $Prices = array();

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if (strstr($key, 'id'))
            {
                $IDs[] = $value;
            }
            if (strstr($key, 'price'))
            {
                $Prices[] = $value;
            }
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < count($IDs); $i++) {
            $price_update = "UPDATE prices SET price='".$Prices[$i]."' WHERE id='".$IDs[$i]."'";
            $send_update = $instance->query($price_update);
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: So, did you run your code? If yes - what happens, errors or what? If no - what are you waiting for?

Comment: Is there an error in this line: <input type="number" name ="price[]; ?>" class="price-update" value="" min="1" max="999999999" />

Comment: Accesses the PHP file just fine, I get the "Data submitted" popup. But nothing is done with the database. I figure it's a problem with the way I'm packaging, sending, and unpacking data through $_POST. Seems to work just fine whenever I have a standalone form (static, not created through loop) and I take away the foreach loop in PHP to unpack.

Comment: @gaganshera No, there is not.

Comment: Just verify if the name attribute of your price input is being correctly placed. Also do a print_r($_POST) to see how the data was received on the server.

Comment: I get this from print_r():

Comment: ?submit=Submit+Changes&price%5B%5D%3B+%3F>=5612&id%5B%5D=6&price%5B%5D%3B+%3F>=25&id%5B%5D=5&price%5B%5D%3B+%3F>=52&id%5B%5D=3&price%5B%5D%3B+%3F>=&id%5B%5D=2&price%5B%5D%3B+%3F>=&id%5B%5D=8

Comment: That's after inputting 3 rows of prices changes.

Comment: Well it seems this got lost into oblivion